# Dividing in while loops in R

Tags: r, while-loop

I'm trying to write a very simple while loop and got stuck on very simple division.

So this works as expected:

```
> i = 100
> (i+1)/2
[1] 50.5
```

But when I run this I'll get an infinite loop of 1s

```
i = 100
while (i > 0.001) {
  i = (i+1)/2
  print(i)
}

[1] 1
[1] 1
...
```

I tried changing the operation and condition to multiplication and it works fine:

```
> i = 100
> while (i < 1000) {
+   i = (i+1)*2
+   print(i)
+ }
[1] 202
[1] 406
[1] 814
[1] 1630
```

Will be grateful for some short explanation what's going on during the division.

Comment: If you're adding one, it will always be above .5 (actually 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're adding one to what you're dividing, as the number approaches 1, you're adding one, so it divides 2 / 2, ending back up with one, so the limit is 1. Example:

```
n <- c(1000, numeric(length = 49))

for (i in seq(50)[-1]) n[i] <- (n[i - 1] + 1) / 2

n
##  [1] 1000.000000  500.500000  250.750000  125.875000   63.437500   32.218750   16.609375
##  [8]    8.804688    4.902344    2.951172    1.975586    1.487793    1.243896    1.121948
## [15]    1.060974    1.030487    1.015244    1.007622    1.003811    1.001905    1.000953
## [22]    1.000476    1.000238    1.000119    1.000060    1.000030    1.000015    1.000007
## [29]    1.000004    1.000002    1.000001    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
## [36]    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
## [43]    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
## [50]    1.000000
```